# Can I put a start date on my cv?

Tags: resume, job-search, human-resources

I made a speculative enquiry to a firm, who said they would keep my cv on file for suitable opportunities.

I was going to send them an updated cv this week, as I have recently completed a benchmark professional qualification.

Can I include the date I'm available from on my cv ie.available from Mid June onwards?

Comment: Why do you think that you can not?

Comment: I thought may be it might be a bit diva-ish?

Comment: If your currently employed, do you plan on giving your current employer 2 weeks notice?

Comment: I would call it an availability date, and not a start date

Answer (score 1):

Yes period, although it's also practical if that is a hard 'no earlier date', such as if you are in school until that time or are planning a move.

Comment: You can just say what your notice period is in the cover letter

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, I already did it before when looking for summer or student jobs. As for a "real" job, I can't see why you couldn't as you could be employed elsewhere and have for instance a 2 month notice before being able to quit.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure it fits the format of your CV. Cv formats are more open to the situation than many traditional resumes would be considered. One of the more important things to stay consistent and to make sure you are documenting what is important from your work/educational history.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter if you do or not, but these types of things tend to be present in a cover letter stating any notice period you have to work out in your current situation, so it'll sort of depend. If I were you, I'd definitely prepare myself for being asked anyway, as it may get forgotten about or ignored (*these things happen*).

The only issue with doing this though is that once '*mid June*' rolls around and if you haven't found anything, you'll need to update your CV again otherwise it'll look outdated which will work against you if you send it out to a prospective employer.